# Building Apache Thrift in Redhat and Fedora

Tags: redhat, thrift, thrift-protocol, fedora16

I want to use Apache Thrift in Redhat and Fedora . Are there some known issues in using it in these platforms as the doc says only CentOS and Ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RedHat and Centos are almost identical platforms and Apache Thrift works well on both. Fedora is also very similar to the prior distros with the benefit of more modern packages and addons, and Apache Thrift also runs well there.